# PostgreSQL получить кортеж данных из столбца

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Пытаюсь получить кортеж данных из таблицы в БД следующим образом

```
kom = "SELECT nickname FROM ch_{}".format(chat_id)
curs = c.execute(kom)
print(curs)
```

При вызове последнего `print` получаю в выводе `__None__` и дальше при

```
data = curs.fetchall()
```

ловлю `traceback` по `AttributeError`
Подключаюсь к таблице через `pgAdmin` - записи есть
[image: скрин с БД]
Возникает тогда вопрос - в чем моя ошибка при получении этого кортежа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в переменной `c` объект реализующий DB-API, то `execute()` должен возвращать `None`. Правильный код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
kom = "SELECT nickname FROM ch_{}".format(chat_id)
c.execute(kom)
data = c.fetchall()
```